# Matching QuerySets in Django Testing

Tags: python, django, docker, testing

I have a Django application and in my testing I run this code:

```
def test_search_keywords_logic(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('search-results'), { 'q': 'test11' })
    nt.assert_equal(response.status_code, 200)
    nt.assert_equal(response.context['query_string'], 'test11')
    nt.assert_equal(response.context['total_results'], 1)
    nt.assert_equal(response.context['found_results'], True)
    qs = QuerySet(CaseStudy.objects.filter(title='test1'))
    nt.assert_queryset_equal(response.context['study_results'], qs)
```

The last line: `nt.assert_queryset_equal(response.context['study_results'], qs)`
gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'`

I'm not sure what it means.  All I want to do is assert that the queryset returned in the context variable 'study_results' is a match to what I know it should be `CaseStudy.objects.get(title='test1')` should return the correct CaseStudy object as it's the only one in the test db.  However, it doesn't seem to work.  I also tried just comparing the response context 'study_results' to `<CaseStudy: test1>`and even tried wrapping it in a `QuerySet()`.  It still didn't work, seemed to see my `QuerySet()` for test1 as the test1 string divided into a list of the single characters.

I've tried using both `nt.assert_equal()` and `nt.assert_queryset_equal()`  Neither work.

What would be the proper/working way to have these assertions pass?  I know the study_results context returns the CaseStudy: test1 in this case.  I just can't seem to get it to match in the assertion.  Since I'm getting it from `objects.filter` it's already a queryset, but even with `.get()` I couldn't get it to work.

My problem seems to be on the right side of the comparison, even when I just put in `'test1` or `<CaseStudy: test1>` or `QuerySet('test1')` it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Encountered this error using this code:

```
    qs = CaseStudy.objects.filter(title='test1')
    nt.assert_queryset_equal(response.context['study_results'], qs)
```

The error:

```
FAIL: test_search_keywords_logic (sasite.tests.tests.TestSearch)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/sasite/tests/tests.py", line 62, in test_search_keywords_logic
    nt.assert_queryset_equal(response.context['study_results'], qs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 972, in assertQuerysetEqual
    return self.assertEqual(list(items), values, msg=msg)
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['test1'] != [test1]
First differing element 0:
'test1'
test1
- ['test1']
?  -     -
+ [test1]
```

EDIT2:

relevant search-results view code:

```
keywords_dicts_study = CaseStudy.objects.all().values('pk', 'keywords', 'category')
match_set_study = set()
target = []
for kd in keywords_dicts_study:
    keywords = kd['keywords'].split(',')
    for word in keywords:
        target.append(word)
    target.append(kd['category'])

    for query in normalize_query(query_string):
        for x in target:
            if query.lower().strip(',').strip() == x.lower().strip():
                match_set_study.add(kd['pk'])
```

EDIT3:

I changed the code to this:

```
qs = CaseStudy.objects.filter(title='test1')
nt.assert_equal(response.context['study_results'], [qs])
```

and now get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/sasite/tests/tests.py", line 62, in test_search_keywords_logic
    nt.assert_queryset_equal(response.context['study_results'], [qs])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 972, in assertQuerysetEqual
    return self.assertEqual(list(items), values, msg=msg)
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['test1'] != [<QuerySet [test1]>]
First differing element 0:
'test1'
<QuerySet [test1]>
- ['test1']
+ [<QuerySet [test1]>]
```

So it sees my `[qs]` as a QuerySet now.  But it doesn't seem that `response.context['page_results']` is a QuerySet itself.  Should I not be using `nt.assert_queryset_equal()` here?  And just use `nt.assert_equal()`?

What exactly is the `response.context['page_results']`?  Is it a QuerySet on it's own?  Because doesn't seem so.  It comes up as `['test1']`.  If I change `[qs]` to `qs` then I get `'[test1]'` as the value.  I can't seem to get them to align correctly.

My goal is have `nt.assert_queryset_equal()` end up as true using `response.contex['study_results']` and `CaseStudy.objects.filter(title='test1')`

Can someone suggest a method to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The view code is incomplete. It is missing the context creation, and without it is unclear what `page_results` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're calling QuerySet on that query. `filter()` already returns a queryset; there doesn't seem to be any reason to wrap it in another. You should remove that.

```
qs = CaseStudy.objects.filter(title='test1')
nt.assert_queryset_equal(response.context['study_results'], qs)
```

Comment: Yes just realized that haha.  Switched my code to what you just suggested even before I read your answer.  Testing now, if it works I'll accept the answer.  Thanks

Comment: Read my edit for what happened with the code you suggested.

Comment: You should probably show the code for the search-results view.

Comment: Okay will do.  Added the code.  Just want to get this call to assert_queryset_equal to succeed.  I can tell its accessing the correct data, and I have the correct title and everything.  But it just isn't displaying correctly when it goes to match it.

Comment: I ended up using the code you suggested and it still didn't work.  I got the result in the first EDIT

Comment: It seems nothing works when I use `assert_queryset_equal()`  So in the end I just used `assert_equal()` with the items title and then the title of the same item pulled from db ahead of time since I knew it was there for the test.  It's not elegant, but this is wasting time now since I can't seem to match querysets with that function.